# How do I find the equation of a parabola given the max, and two points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given the points (2, -1) and (10,-1) and also a max of 4.  How would I go about finding the equation of the parabola given this info?

Comment: You should be able to deduce first that the vertex of your parabola is at $(6,4)$ (why?). You now have three points; substitute the appropriate values in $y=ax^2+bx+c$, and you now have three equations in three unknowns.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are using the following form for the equation of a parabola:

If the vertex of the parabola is located at $(h,k)$, then the equation of the parabola is $$\tag{1}y=a(x-h)^2+k$$
for some constant $a$.

That this holds can be seen by taking the graph of  the parabola $y=ax^2$ and translating it $h$ units to the right and $k$ units up.

Some notes:

1) The line $x=h$ is the  line of symmetry of the parabola.

2) $a$ is the "scaling factor". The larger $a$ is in absolute value, the "narrower" the parabola is.

3) If $a>0$, the parabola opens up and $k$ is the minimum value of the $y$ coordinates on the parabola

4) If $a<0$, the parabola opens down and $k$ is the maximum value of the $y$ coordinates on the parabola

An example is shown below.

[image]

---

As made clear by Ross and Jonas, you should find the vertex first, then write the equation in the form (1) above. There will still be the unknown $a$ in the equation at this point. To find it, substitute the information given by one of the given points into the equation and solve for $a$.

Comment: Such a great answer and graph. How did you drawn and took that graph, David? Which programme did you used for example?

Comment: @KerimAtasoy Thanks. It was done with the Javascript library [JSXgraph](http://www.jsxgraph.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the $y$ values of those points are equal, which implies they are equidistant from the axis of symmetry.  Therefore the vertex is at $(6,4)$.  Since $x^2$ increases from $0$ to $16$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $4$, but your parabola decreases by $5$ when you go $4$ units to the right (or left) of the vertex, there must be a scaling factor of $-\frac{5}{16}$.  So I would conclude that $y=-\frac{5}{16}(x-6)^2+4$ is the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your max is the maximum $y$ coordinate as $x$ gets larger in absolute value.  As the $y$ components are the same in the points you have, the max must come symmetrically between them, at $x=6$.  So our parabola is $y=a(x-6)^2+b$.  If you put these two points into this equation, you have two simultaneous equations in two unknowns.